# Can you identify this sci-fi trilogy from the 90s?

Tags: story-identification

I remember very little of the trilogy except:

- the main character is a 'chosen-one' archetype who is smuggled out of someplace in a boat as a boy
- he fails in his quest many years later, something something time travel, and he ends up back in the same city
- I believe the final scene is of him as the boatman who is smuggling the chosen one out of the city to begin the cycle anew...
- I remember the titles all having the same format and being sort of alliterative

That's all I've had to go one since I read them as a tween and it's been driving me crazy for years. I'm sure they were rather bad, but I'd like to scan them again regardless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it by scanning through the locus index. It is the Confluence trilogy by Paul J. McCauley, and the first book is called Child of the River. (The alliteration I was thinking of was the third volume, Shrine of Stars.)